# Comparing Breusch-Pagan test results

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, least-squares

Suppose I have two regression models:

1. `Y = B1 + B2.X`
2. `ln(Y) = B1 + B2.X`

If I run the Breusch-Pagan test by regressing the residual square with `X` for both models and find that the $F$ value for model (1) is lower than model (2), is it safe to conclude that model (2) is less susceptible to heteroskedasticity and thereby taking the log of the dependent variable mitigate heteroskedasticity?